# How to add ± to each element in the List?

Tags: list-manipulation

**I just want to add ±  with Function** `Thread`

*Output that I want*

`{±1, ±2, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9}`

```
Thread[{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}, "\[PlusMinus]"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PlusMinus /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}
```

> {±1, ±2, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9}

If you have to use `Thread` you can do:

```
Thread @ PlusMinus @ {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}
```

> {±1, ±2, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9}

or

```
Thread[Prefix[foo /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}, "±"]]
```

> {±1, ±2, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9}

```
Prefix[foo @ #, #2] & @@@ Thread[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}, "±"}]
```

> {±1, ±2, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9}

Comment: What's wrong with `Thread` in this code here?

Comment: @kile, added alternative ways to use `Thread` to get the desired result.